# Download a pdf streamed by a java webservice (POST)

Tags: java, jquery, web-services, post

I have a webservice that is called by POST method :

```
  @Path("/ficheAction/")
  @POST
  @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  @Produces("application/pdf")
  public Response ficheAction(final ParamSyntheseFicheActionDto paramSyntheseFicheAction) throws EngineException {
  [...]
     return Response.ok(output.toByteArray(), "application/pdf")
        .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = " + name + ".pdf").build();
  }
```

This webservice use the parameters (Json) from my js :

```
  [...]    
  $.ajax({
        url : webServiceUrl,
        // 
        type : "POST",
        // Content type to send to the server
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : pData,
        dataType : "json",
        success : pCallback,
        cache : false,
    });
```

The webservice seams to work, but on the client side, the navigator doesn't open the file (pdf).

I've test with GET instead of POST (simplifying the attributes), and it works, but not in POST...
When i look at the response of the webservice in the chrome debug, i can see that there is a response starting with "%PDF-1.5"... But the download does not start...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use GET method.

To download the file, do not use ajax just call your webservice by simple link.

```
<a href="http://your-server.com/ficheAction">Download</a>
```

Or use that simple js script:

```
window.open("http://your-server.com/ficheAction");
```