# webservice to return excel sheet without getting it downloaded at client end

Tags: java, jquery, html, excel, web-services

I have  java semirestful webservices code as follows

```
 @Path("/todo")
 public class TodoResource  
 { 
 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
 public  Response getfile()
 {
  File file =new File("D:\\Test.xls"); // Initialize this to the File path you   want to   serve.
  return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
   } 
  }
```

When I call the web service   from client end which employs ajax call with jquery I dont want to download this file instead I just want to store the file in some parameter and parse it.
How that can be done?

Comment: check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565845/download-a-pdf-streamed-by-a-java-webservice-post?rq=1